# Checking array for a value

Tags: python, debugging, indexing

I have an array as below.

```
testgrid = [
     [9, 1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 7, 5, 6],
     [9, 1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 7, 5, 6],
     [9, 1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 7, 5, 6],
     [9, 1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 7, 5, 6],
     [9, 1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 7, 5, 6],
     [9, 1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 7, 5, 6],
     [9, 1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 7, 5, 6],
     [9, 1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 7, 5, 6],
     [9, 1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 7, 5, 6]]
```

On passing the testgrid into the following function it should return all indexes that do not contain a value of zero currently it returns (0, 0).  I would expect all indexes to be returned on this grid. It seems to be checking the indexes rather than the value stored at that index.  I am a noob so probably am missing something obvious here.

```
def not_empty_location(grid):

    # checks if current location is empty and assign location not empty
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if grid[i][j] != 0:
                return (i, j)
    return None
```

Comment: Your loops are returning on the very first iteration. You'd have to store results to an array and return the results after the for loops have run to completion

Comment: Yes, your program currently says that it should return the coordinates of the first non-zero element.

Comment: Consider upvoting the answer too, if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `yield` instead of `return`:

```py
def not_empty_location(grid):

    # checks if current location is empty and assign location not empty
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if grid[i][j] != 0:
                yield (i, j)
    return None
```

This would return all the values as a `generator` which can then simply be converted into a `list`.

Output:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (6, 0), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 0), (7, 1), (7, 2), (7, 3), (7, 4), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (8, 0), (8, 1), (8, 2), (8, 3), (8, 4), (8, 5), (8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

try by storing the index tuples in a list and return

```
    def not_empty_location(grid):
    result = [] # list to store the index
    # checks if current location is empty and assign location not empty

    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if grid[i][j] != 0:
                result.append( (i, j) )   # In your code you are returning at your very first success of getting != 0 
    return result
```